# Get the Propertyname on owning type c#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have the following construct:

```
class Bla
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello my name is " + GetMyVariableName();

    }

    private string GetMyVariableName()
    {
        return "";//do magic here to determine the Variable name at the class that owns the Property
    }
}

class Fasel
{
    public Bla SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public Bla AnotherProperty { get; set; }

    void DoSomeAction()
    {
        SomeProperty = new Bla();
        AnotherProperty = new Bla();

        string name = SomeProperty.Hello(); //this sould return "Hello my name is SomeProperty"

        name = AnotherProperty.Hello(); ////this sould return "Hello my name is AnotherProperty"
    }
}
```

This looks easy to solve as i just do the reflection stuff to determine the name in owning class but in my special case i can't do that.  I need to know in the Property what is the name of it in the class that owns it.

Comment: You cannot do this without creating your own version of the CLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely, utterly, impossible.

A single instance can be referenced by multiple properties; there is no connection between an object and the properties it's referenced by.  (Except in the GC, which won't tell you about it)

In addition, JIT inlining can mean that the property won't necessarily be involved at all.
Plus, local variable names do not exist in optimized binaries.

Comment: Well not impossible, just really really really hard. You could get the method Hello is being called from by using the Stack Trace. Then use the method body to figure it out. Although even from there I can't see a good way to do it. But for all intents and purposes your answer is about right.

Comment: @Yuriy: No; it really is impossible.  You can't reliably figure out where in the method your call originated for non-trivial methods.  (Except maybe if you duplicate the JITter, or create a second process and attach it to the first one as a managed debugger, both of which would be _insane_ and impossible)

Comment: Your very question means that something is seriously wrong in your design, but it should be possible if you only need to support properties (and not local variables). You can look at the stack trace to find the object whose method is calling Bla.Hello(), then use reflection to go over all the object's properties and fields, and find one whose value is the Bla instance.

Comment: @Ran: That also won't work. What if two properties point to the same instance? **What if the method uses a property from a different instance?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are asking for is possible.  Maybe one way to do it would be for the constructor of Bla to take a string, then when you create the instance, you can pass in the string:

```
SomeProperty = new Bla("SomeProperty");
AnotherProperty = new Bla("AnotherProperty");
```

Comment: that is the current solution for it, but if someone renames the property and forgets about the Constructor the logic behind is failing but the compiler can't check that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can reliabily do this with reflection and it's a terrible idea to want to in the first place. It's possible to invoke a method on on instance without ever declaring a variable for it. For example:

```
string name=new Bla().Hello();
```

In this scenario what would your method print..?